# How to stop Java Scanner from accepting input

Tags: java, input, timer, java.util.scanner

So, I am working on a quiz taking program that works from the command line and the quizzes have time limits. What I want to do, is to stop the quiz right when the user's time is up even if they're in the middle of answering a question. I am using Java's Scanner to get the user's input, so I want to essentially tell the Scanner object to terminate even if it's in the middle of accepting input.

Now, I know that I can retroactively punish a user for going over time after the fact, but I simply want the quiz to terminate once the time limit has been exceeded. Is there any way to do this with multithreading for example?

Comment: Rethink your problem: is it that you want to get Scanner to stop taking input, or is is that you want to stop using whatever input you get from Scanner once the time limit is elapsed? Hint: check your time limit each time you take input.

Comment: I noted this in the question. I don't want to check whether or not the user has exceeded the time limit each time I get an answer, I need a way of stopping the quiz right when the user exceeds the time limit.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A Java Scanner is using blocking operations. It is not possible to stop it. Not even using `Thread.interrupt();`

You can however read using a `BufferedLineReader` and be able to stop the thread. It's not a neat solution, as it involves pausing for short moments (otherwise it would use 100 % CPU), but it does work.

```
public static class ConsoleInputReadTask {
    private final AtomicBoolean stop = new AtomicBoolean();

    public void stop() {
        stop.set(true);
    }

    public String requestInput() throws IOException {
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        System.out.println("ConsoleInputReadTask run() called.");
        String input;
        do {
            System.out.println("Please type something: ");
            try {
                // wait until we have data to complete a readLine()
                while (!br.ready() && !stop.get()) {
                    Thread.sleep(200);
                }
                input = br.readLine();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                System.out.println("ConsoleInputReadTask() cancelled");
                return null;
            }
        } while ("".equals(input));
        System.out.println("Thank You for providing input!");
        return input;
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    final Thread scannerThread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                String string = new ConsoleInputReadTask().requestInput();
                System.out.println("Input: " + string);
            }
            catch (IOException e) {
                throw new RuntimeException(e);
            }
        }
    });
    scannerThread.start();

    new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(5000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                throw new RuntimeException(e);
            }
            scannerThread.interrupt();
        }
    }).start();
 }
```

Comment: Once the main thread is interrupted, can I continue on to finalizing the quiz score and displaying it to the user? Can you show that in the code? Thanks.

Comment: @RespectMyAuthoritah You see where this is going. Killing the thread doing the input from a thread that does nothing but wait for the timeout to expire: where does this program continue? It is indeed kind of "too broad" as you'll have to ponder over a set of design decisions... (No, I didn't vote for closing.)

Comment: Well, I would want it to continue on with the main thread's workflow. Is that not possible? I am not asking for how to design my program, but simply how to stop the scanner and go on with the rest of the program.

Comment: @RespectMyAuthoritah It turns out the process is a bit more complicated then I expected... my answer is not fully correct.

Comment: @RespectMyAuthoritah I have edited with a better example. Play around with it and try to understand it, if this doesn't help you then I am afraid you have taken water over your head and should implement a simpler solution.

Answer (score -2):

Here is your solution, people:

```java
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
    {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(new BufferedInputStream(System.in), "UTF-8");
        String item;
        
        while (true)
        {
            System.out.print("Give me some input:\t");
            if (!(item = sc.nextLine()).equals(""))
                System.out.println("\nYour Input was:\t" + item);
            else
                break;
        }
        
        System.out.println("Goodbye, see you again!");
    }
```

Example Output:

```
Give me some input: Your

Your Input was: Your
Give me some input: Programming

Your Input was: Programming
Give me some input: Knowledge

Your Input was: Knowledge
Give me some input: Sucks

Your Input was: Sucks
Give me some input: !!!

Your Input was: !!!
Give me some input: In the next line I'll just type ENTER so that my input is recognized as empty ;-)

Your Input was: In the next line I'll just type ENTER so that my input is recognized as empty ;-)
Give me some input: 
Goodbye, see you again!
```

Comment: I'm not exactly seeing how this does "stop the quiz right when the user's time is up even if they're in the middle of answering a question"?